# What's the difference between Subclipse Get Contents and Get Revision?

Tags: svn, version-control, eclipse-plugin, subclipse, revision

When using the Eclipse->Team->Show History view, what's the difference between using Subclipse "Get Contents" and "Get Revision" options on a revision of a file?

Is there any way to see what svn commands Subclipse is issuing behind the scenes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the Subclipse manual (Help > Help Contents):

> **Get Contents**
>
> Use this option to update the contents
>   of the selected file in your working
>   copy with the contents of the revision
>   in the repository. The revision number
>   of your local file is not changed by
>   this option.
>
> This option is only valid when the
>   resource history was launched for an
>   individual file in a local working
>   copy.
>
> **Get Revision**
>
> Use this option to replace the file in
>   your working copy with the selected
>   revision in the repository. The
>   revision number of your local file is
>   changed to the selected revision.
>
> This option is only valid when the
>   resource history was launched for an
>   individual file in a local working
>   copy.

Pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: I often use "Get Contents" in the case if somebody has checked in something inadvertently, so I just get the current content replaced with the last version of it.

Answer (score 1):

Get contents just shows you the file's contents, while get revision replaces your version of the file.

To see the commands run by subclipse in the console view you should check the "Show SVN console automatically when command is run" option in tools/preferences/team/svn/console.

Comment: I could only accept one answer, but thanks for answering my 2nd question also!